# How to dynamically generate attributes for a QML Item?

Tags: qt, qml

In a QML application I'm coding, I am always writing the sames attributes names with different values. For example :

```
Image{
    source:"qrc:/..."
    Layout.preferredWidth: 124 //Always
    Layout.preferredHeight: 229 //the same
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter //3 lines
    Layout.topMargin: convertHeight(40)
    Layout.bottomMargin: convertHeight(26)
}
```

would it be possible to define a function that generates dynamic attributes :

```
function sizeProps(width,height){
    return {
        Layout.preferredWidth : width,
        Layout.preferredHeight : height,
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    }
}
```

and use the dynamically generated attributes like this ?

```
Image{
    source:"qrc:/..."
    {sizeProps(124,229)}
    Layout.topMargin: convertHeight(40)
    Layout.bottomMargin: convertHeight(26)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, but you can create a custom component and reuse your new type. [[1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html)]

Either by defining an [inline component](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html#inline-components) like:

```
component Img: Image {
    property size size: Qt.size(width, height)  /* default value */

    Layout.preferredWidth: size.width
    Layout.preferredHeight: size.height
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
}

// usage: 
Img { size{width: 100; height: 200} }
```

Or defining it in a separate `.qml` file [[3](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html#custom-qml-type-definition)].

**Img.qml**

```
Image {
    property size size: Qt.size(width, height)
    
    Layout.preferredWidth: size.width
    Layout.preferredHeight: size.height
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
}

// usage: (same as inline component)
Img { size{width: 100; height: 200} }
```

But if you prefer using functions, you can do this too, but I do not recommend it.

```
function initImgLayout(item, width, height) {
    item.Layout.preferredWidth = width;
    item.Layout.preferredHeight = height;
    item.Layout.alignment = Qt.AlignHCenter;
}

Image {
    Component.onCompleted: initImgLayout(this, 100, 200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! My favourite one is the last one, but why don't you recommend it ?

Comment: @ElevenJune As I understand your question, you want to reuse some predefined properties for a component. The best way to do this in QML is by defining a new type, as explained above. However, using the last solution is not recommended as it is neither declarative nor very clean.

Comment: @ElevenJune Also, by using `initImgLayout`, you may not be able to create bindings as easily as in the declarative solution.

Comment: Ok ! I know understand why this is a bad solution !

Answer (score 0):

I want to highlight the `Img.qml` aspect of smr's answer.

For large QML projects, look for ways to reduce complexity with components. I often subclass QML components with properties tailored for my app.

In the following demo, I choose to make:

- `AppText` is a customization of `Text`

  - `AppHeading1` is a customization of `AppText`
  - `AppHeading2` is a customization of `AppText`
- `AppImage` is a customization of `Image`

  - This includes all your customizations
- `AppPage` is a customization of `Page` combined with `ScrollView` and `ColumnLayout`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
AppPage {
    title: "AppImage Example"
    AppHeading1 { text: "AppImage Example" }
    AppHeading2 { text: "Red Circle" }
    AppImage { source: "red-circle.svg" }
    AppHeading2 { text: "Green Triangle" }
    AppImage { source: "green-triangle.svg" }
}

// AppPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    default property alias data: columnLayout.data
    ScrollView {
        id: scrollView
        anchors.fill: parent
        ScrollBar.vertical {
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            width: 20
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            width: scrollView.width - 20
        }
    }
}

// AppText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Text {
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
}

// AppHeading1.qml
import QtQuick.Layouts
AppText {
    Layout.topMargin: 10
    font.pointSize: 20
    font.bold: true
    color: "blue"
}

// AppHeading2.qml
import QtQuick.Layouts
AppText {
    Layout.topMargin: 10
    font.pointSize: 14
    color: "orange"
}

// AppImage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Image {
    Layout.preferredWidth: 124
    Layout.preferredHeight: 229
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    Layout.topMargin: convertHeight(40)
    Layout.bottomMargin: convertHeight(26)
    cache: false
    function convertHeight(h) {
        return h;
    } 
}

// red-circle.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 124 229">
<rect width="124" height="229" fill="lightblue" />
<circle cx="62" cy="115" r="30" fill="red" />
</svg>

// green-triangle.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 124 229">
<rect width="124" height="229" fill="lightblue" />
<path d="M 62 85 L 92 145 L 32 145 Z" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It is what I tend to do as well, excatly like you with the Text for example. What I forgot to say in my post is that even with custom component, the width and height still varies according to the screen. I have to specify the width and height of each custom component.